# strftime performance vs. snprintf

Tags: c++, c, performance, strftime, printf

I have run into an interesting performance conundrum but before I start delving into glibc and entering bugs left right and center I just wanted to get to get any insight that might be out there.

I have code that in one of the functions does this:

```
gettimeofday( &tv, 0);
localtime_r( &tv.tv_sec, &local_tm );
char result[25];
strftime( result, 24, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &local_tm);
```

The rest of the code is irrelevant for this question. When I replace it with this:

```
gettimeofday( &tv, 0);
localtime_r( &tv.tv_sec, &local_tm );
char result[25];
snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
         local_tm.tm_year+1900, local_tm.tm_mon+1,
         local_tm.tm_mday, local_tm.tm_hour, local_tm.tm_min,
         local_tm.tm_sec);
```

on average I get 20% performance boost.

Has anyone ran into this?  Is this OS specific?

Comment: What OS/compiler are you using?

Comment: So `snprintf` is more efficient than `strftime` on your system. This wouldn't be considered a "bug".

Comment: `strftime` may have to deal with localization (more than `snprintf` does).

Comment: @SethCarnegie This was done on RHEL 4 v3.4.6  I am going to test on Ubuntu 10.04 a little later today.

Comment: @GregHewgill I wasn't looking at this as a bug just looking for a reason.

Comment: I see. I guess I was misled by your "start...entering bugs left right and center".

Comment: I ran into the same thing, did some more tests and created this Gist with the code and results: https://gist.github.com/felipou/ad107bbb3a91814679beb22c0686fbeb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX requires `strftime` to call `tzset()` (or act as if it did), which on a linux system will likely stat /etc/timezone and other files, which is slow (compared to snprintf). Setting the `TZ` environment variable will generally give it a great boost.

As was said in the comments it also localizes the message.

Comment: Setting the `TZ` environment variable to a zone name/path probably won't help, but using a POSIX-style zone description like `EST5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2` will certainly speed it up (at the expense of supporting historical DST rule differences).

Comment: Thank you.  I actually found that GLIBC 2.11 has that problem resolved.  Not exactly sure what was the earliest version this happened.